# App fails with permission when try to debug on Android 4.0 device

Tags: android, debugging, versioning, remote-debugging

I've written app for Android 2.2 (target version) and I tried to run it on device with Android 4.0.3 but it fails with granting permission for internet connection. It run without problems on Android 2.3. Is there any way to run that app on A4.0 without changing target SDK version?

My `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pl.niemier.allegro"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ShowAuctionActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SearchFormActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".UserInfoActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ConfigPanelActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: by your short description, that shouldn't make a difference. Please read the logcat and post it if it's not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the SDK target version in you manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Please check if the version number is correct.

I assume you have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` since it works on Android 2.3.

Comment: @Hauleth Could you make a test and remove `android:targetSdkVersion="10"` from the manifest?